# How to approach my manager about more pay for a recent promotion with no accompanying pay rise?

Tags: promotion

I was asked to take a management job as our current manger left. I tentatively accepted the position but have not been offered any compensation only expectation of it in the form of percent increase over time. I have taken on a lot more responsibility and feel I should be compensated better initially for doing so.

It is only a good opportunity for a better job title but I don't necessarily need this job. I think the company is in a hard place and I am the best option for a quick smooth fix so I think that's good, but the responsibility level I have and am taking on is much greater and I think I need more compensation in money to match not only my new position but my current credentials.

My office is separate from where my boss and CEO are located so meeting to talk requires special trips. I have considered emailing but am afraid it will look cowardly or worst yet will just be ignored. I like email because I can argue my point clearly and write it all down organized. I am not good at that in person.

So far I am being severely low balled in the pay and don't know the best way to proceed in any case. Should I express my concerns via email? In the event something better is not negotiated or worse no response, how should I handle that without cutting myself short or burning bridges?

Answer (score 6):

> Should I express my concerns via email?

No. This is something that clearly should be discussed face-to-face.

Sit down during a quiet period and think.

First determine what it is specifically that you want. You need to determine how much more money you feel you should receive. And you need to determine over what period of time you think you should receive it.

Remember that sometimes people are given a role change first, followed up by an increase in compensation later. That's not always the case, but it's not unheard of, either.

Then you need to determine reasons why you deserve this increase. Consider how you are helping the company now and how that will change going forward. Consider how you will respond if your increase is denied, or if a smaller increase is granted, or it the company proposes to stretch it out over a longer period of time.

Write these down in an organized fashion, then practice talking about it. Imagine the conversation you will be having with your boss, what he/she might say, and how you will answer. Practice some more.

When you have gotten to the point where you feel you can clearly articulate these issues, then ask your boss for a few minutes of time.

Then, go knock your boss dead with your convincing, coherent discussion!

(also, read [Is it okay to negotiate a promotional raise via email?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36081/is-it-okay-to-negotiate-a-promotional-raise-via-email) )

Comment: Don't be surprised if the answer is that the promotion gives you the opportunity to _earn_ that raise.  Be prepared to follow up with "ok, then what do I need to do to get there. "